# Random number in range without repeating LABVIEW

Tags: random, repeat, labview

I have this kind of a VI file and I need to add something in order to prevent numbers from repeating. Could you help?
[image: problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than filtering your list of numbers, you would be better off shuffling an array and taking the first few elements.

- Excludes any possibility of duplication
- Removes repeated checks
- Can be easily adjusted for various ranges
- Does not require any loops

[image: Shuffle and grab numbers from array]

Comment: Thank you. My professor insisted on doing it that way, but it is practically impossible, so I decided to quit and go in another direction.